# iOS 7 - Blurred view with child GLKViewController (FXBlurView)

Tags: ios, opengl-es, blur, childviewcontroller

I'm using the popular FXBlurView library to add an overlay blurred view to my app.

The main view controller contains a child view controller which is a GLKViewController with OpenGL content.

Adding a blurred view to the parent vc doesn't take into account any content of the child vc.
I've tried to add the blur view to the main window instead of the vc view but the result is the same.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

For anybody interested in this topic I've found a potential solution and reported the issue here: https://github.com/nicklockwood/FXBlurView/issues/102